# Iterating over a numpy array and operating on each element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy array of size 8x8.
Here is the numpy array:

```
QuantTable = np.array([[16, 11 ,10, 16, 24, 40, 51, 61],
                    [12, 12, 14, 19, 26, 58, 60, 55],
                    [14, 13, 16, 24, 40, 57, 69, 56],
                    [14, 17, 22, 29, 51, 87, 80, 62],
                    [18, 22, 37, 29, 51, 87, 80, 62],
                    [24, 35, 55, 64, 81, 109, 103, 77],
                    [49, 64, 78, 87, 103, 121, 120, 101],
                    [72, 92, 95, 98, 112, 100, 103, 99]])
```

I would like to perform the operations on the elements in the array.
I have created a function that accepts a scaling factor value and a Numpy Array.
Here it is:

```
def quantizationTable(Qval, QuantTable):
    if Qval < 50:
        scalingFactor = 5000/Qval
        for x in range(QuantTable):
            for y in range(QuantTable):
                QuantTable[x][y] = ((scalingFactor * QuantTable[x][y] + 50/100)
                if QuantTable[x][y] == 0:
                    QuantTable[x][y] = 1
    return QuantTable
    else:
        scalingFactor = 200 - 2(Qval)
        for x in range(QuantTable):
            for y in range(QuantTable):
                QuantTable[x][y] = ((scalingFactor * QuantTable[x][y] + 50/100)
                if QuantTable[x][y] == 0:
                    QuantTable[x][y] = 1

return QuantTable
```

I am having trouble iterating over the numpy array and performing my operations. I am trying to apply the formula
((Scaling factor value * element of numpy array + 50)/100) to every element of the numpy array and return the modified array.
Can someone please help?

Comment: `I am having trouble iterating over the numpy array and performing my operations.` - Elaborate?

Comment: Why the loops? `return scalingFactor * QuantTable + 50/100`

Comment: Because I need to perform the operation on each and every element. Please correct me if I am wrong in my logic itself. Thanks.

Comment: @Feodoran I thought loops are the only way I can iterate over each element of the numpy array.

Comment: You don't need to iterate yourself, numpy can do this much faster than any loop in Python could do.

Comment: @SanketWagh no - indeed, using loops is *the inadvisable way* of achieving what you want. The whole **point** of `numpy` arrays is that they allow vectorized operations that are fast and efficient.

Comment: Thank you both for the input, I shall keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the loops, and the indexing. Numpy automatically broadcasts those operations. Also, a lot of your code can be taken out of the `if...else` statements.

```
def quantizationTable(Qval, QuantTable):
    QuantTable = np.asarray(QuantTable, dtype=np.float32)
    if int(Qval) < 50:
        scalingFactor = 5000 / Qval
    else:
        scalingFactor = 200 - 2 * Qval # confirm that this is what you want? 

    QuantTable *= scalingFactor + 0.5
    QuantTable[QuantTable == 0] = 1

    return QuantTable
```

Comment: You need to be careful with in-place operations. If `QuantTable` is an integer array that would lead to truncation (because scaling is a float).

Comment: @MSeifert Oh, good point. I should probably add a `np.asarray(..., dtype)` cast.

Comment: scalingFactor = 200 - 2 * Qval -> This is what I want.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I used this answer and modified it a little. It works like a charm. Thanks.