# Subtract the average of first and last value of each row from all values in the row

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, for-loop

I have a numpy array that looks like this:

```
77.132  2.075   63.365  74.880
49.851  22.480  19.806  76.053
16.911  8.834   68.536  95.339
0.395   51.219  81.262  61.253
72.176  29.188  91.777  71.458
54.254  14.217  37.334  67.413
44.183  43.401  61.777  51.314
65.040  60.104  80.522  52.165
90.865  31.924  9.046   30.070
11.398  82.868  4.690   62.629
```

and what I'm trying to do is

- find the average of the first and last item in each row
- subtract this average from each pixel in that row
- repeat for each row
- create a new image of subtracted pixels.

I've tried it using `for` loops but I can't get it working:

```
import numpy as np

#   Create random arrays to simulate images
np.random.seed(10)
image = 100 * np.random.rand(10, 4)

no_disk_list = []

#for row in image:
#    left, right =   row[0], row[-1]
#    average = (left + right) / 2.0
#    for i in row:
#        no_average = row[i] - average
#        print(average)
#        no_disk_list.append(no_average)

subtracted = np.ones_like(image)
height, width = image.shape
for row in image:
    left, right =   image[0], image[-1]
    average = (left + right) / 2.0
    for element in row:
        subtracted[row, element] = image[row, element] - average
```

Both of the nested loops gives an error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Jeremy/Dropbox/Astro480/NEOWISE/subtract_disk.py", line 17, in <module>
    no_disk_value = row[i] - disk_value

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

for the first loop and

```
  File "C:/Users/Jeremy/Dropbox/Astro480/NEOWISE/subtract_pixels.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(image[row, element])

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

for the second. The questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663988/looping-through-each-item-in-a-numpy-array), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967463/iterating-over-a-numpy-array), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886000/iterating-over-a-numpy-array-and-operating-on-each-element) are of limited use in my situation. Besides, I know that vectorization would be a better way to go, since the image I'll eventually be using has 1.3 million pixels. How can I get the loops working, or even better, vectorize the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly this will work:

```
subtracted = np.ones_like(image)
height, width = image.shape
for row_no, row in enumerate(image):   # keep the row number using enumerate
    left, right = row[0], row[-1]      # you need the first and last value of the ROW!
    average = (left + right) / 2.0
    # Also use enumerate in the inner loop
    for col_no, element in enumerate(row):
        subtracted[row_no, col_no] = element - average
```

You can even use broadcasting ("vectorization") to shorten this considerably:

```
subtracted = image - (image[:, [0]] + image[:, [-1]]) / 2
```

The `image[:, [0]]` is the first column, the `image[:, [-1]]` is the last column. By adding and dividing them by 2 you get a 2D array containing the averages of each row. The final step is subtracting this from the image, which is easy in this case because it will broadcast correctly.

Step-by-step:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
>>> arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
>>> arr[:, [0]]  # first column
array([[ 0],
       [ 5],
       [10],
       [15]])
>>> arr[:, [-1]]  # last column
array([[ 4],
       [ 9],
       [14],
       [19]])
>>> (arr[:, [0]] + arr[:, [-1]]) / 2   # average
array([[  2.],
       [  7.],
       [ 12.],
       [ 17.]])
>>> arr - (arr[:, [0]] + arr[:, [-1]]) / 2  # subtracted
array([[-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.]])
```

Comment: So is `broadcasting` a particular example of `vectorization`?

Comment: Well, yes and no: ["Broadcasting provides a means of vectorizing array operations so that looping occurs in C instead of Python."](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting). It's a technique so that the operation is vectorized (and yes, the addition, division and subtraction are vectorized).